# Выполнить запрос sql по массиву

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT ID, SUMM 
FROM DOCS D 
WHERE D.DATA = '2021-01-01' 
  AND (D.KOD = '020047' OR D.KOD = '020045')
```

Запрос успешно выполняется, возможно сделать чтоб поиск по поля KOD выполнялся по массиву, к примеру типа этого

```
$arr = ['020047', '020045'];
```

```
SELECT ID, SUMM 
FROM DOCS D 
WHERE D.DATA = '2021-01-01' 
AND D.KOD = $arr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$implodedStr = implode('\',\'', $arr); // $implodedStr = implode("','", $arr);

$sql = <<<SQL
SELECT ID, SUMM 
FROM DOCS D 
WHERE D.DATA = '2021-01-01' 
AND D.KOD IN ('$implodedStr')
SQL;
```

---

Надо учесть то, что если это данные от пользователя, то надо будет использовать подготовленные выражения, а не напрямую так вставлять данные в код

Comment: Фигня получится. Внутри IN должен быть список литералов, а будет один литерал со списком внутри. Надо `AND FIND_IN_SET(D.KOD, '$implodedStr')`

Comment: @Akina да, подправил

Comment: Для старого метода доступа, с прямой подстановкой в запрос - прокатит. А вот при использовании PDO - уже вряд ли...

Comment: @Akina О чём я и написал комментарий

Comment: В Laravel будет работать ?

Comment: @Федотов если применять с умом- везде будет работать)